# MVC 4 & Custom jQuery Validation - Numeric Validation ignoring values such as "N/A", "NA" and "n/a"

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, validation

Currently I have a property of tyoe decimal? displayed on my view. Users want the ability to enter in N/A or NA if it is not applicable to them as opposed to leaving it blank.  Can someone point me in the right direction to solve this by using jquery unobtrusive validation?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you trying to validate in jquery or server-side?

Comment: Apologies for not adding that I am using jquery unobtrusive validation

Comment: You can write a custom validation attribute.  I've never had users ask for more work with no percieved benefit like that though.

Comment: Explain more.  Show some code.  What are you using?  Custom validation or a custom method with a jQuery validation plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a custom validator, something like:

```
$.validator.addMethod("NADecimal", function(value, element) {
    return this.optional(element) || value == 'N/A' || value == 'NA' || parseFloat(value) >0 ;
}, "Please specify N/A or decimal value");
```

and then in your validate:

```
$('#myForm').validate({

    rules: {
        "decimalField": { "NADecimal"},
         other rules....
    },
```

Edit:

This said, is your data type decimal on the server side? "N/A" would be useless then.

Comment: That's fine if the OP is using the jQuery Validate plugin.  However, that's presently unclear.

Comment: You're right, I assumed that's what he meant in comment reply.

Comment: Oh I see.  I think he should fix his OP though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Decimal.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx) method here to attempt to parse the input. Given an `out decimal` parameter, it will set the value to whatever it parses if successful, or leave it untouched if parsing fails (returns a bool indicating success or failure).

Comment: I think OP means N/A , NA should pass the validation as well as 1.2, but should fail for empty string.